# I'm trying to add a remove button to a table and only remove that table row in jquery.

Tags: jquery

Instead it is removing all of the table rows. I know there's some way to select just that row using parent/child selectors but not sure the right combo

```
$("#add-another-essay").click(function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('tbody').append("<tr class='essays-new-table-row'>"+$('.essays-new-table-row').html()+"</tr>")
}); 

$("#remove-another-essay").click(function(){
  event.preventDefault();

  $('.essays-new-table-row').remove();
});
```

Comment: Can we see the HTML - I don't know how the remove button relates to the row - is it a child of the row, or is there one remove button, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the row that was clicked:

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
```

Instead of :

```
$('.essays-new-table-row').remove();  //this removes all rows with that class
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kyhe1o93/)

Comment: DOM traversal for the win.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code currently. First thing is you are creating the "remove" button element through jquery, but you are initializing the click event for that button before one actually exists. You have

```
//Add
$("#add-another-essay").click(function(){ ... });
```

Followed by

```
//Remove
$("#remove-another-essay").click(function(){ ... });
```

In your "Add" function, you are creating a new row with the id "remove-another-essay". Which means there is no row called "remove-another-essay" until the add button is clicked. When the page first loads, your "Remove" function is not applied to anything because $("#remove-another-essay") does not exist until you click "Add". The solution is to initialize your "Remove" function at the end of the "Add" function. [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/df2fzonv/1/)

```
$(".add-another-essay").click(function(){
    //build the elements for the row
    $row = $("<tr></tr>");
    $data = $("<td>My Data String</td>");
    $btn = $("<td><button class='remove-another-essay'>Remove</button></td>");

    //put the row together
    $row
        .append($data)
        .append($btn);

    //append the row to the table body
    $('tbody').append($row);

    //IMPORTANT - initialize remove-another-essay button click handler each time a new row is added.
    $(".remove-another-essay").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

Also, you should not dynamically generate an id for an html element in JQuery. Just use classes:

```
$(".remove-another-essay") OR <button class="remove-another-essay">Remove</button>
```

The previous answer does not quite address the OP's code where he is creating the table rows through JQuery. Assuming he has to do this for some reason, I've made a slightly different Fiddle to account for those requirements. [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/df2fzonv/1/)